# Ionic cordova media capture plugin Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I have been making a simple application in Ionic to capture a video and show it as soon as the capturing of a video is done. I have completed till capturing the video by using media capture, but the src generated is from local mobile which is not allowing me and throwing an error:
 
 **Not allowed to load local resource:**  *file:///storage/8699-1C15/DCIM/Camera/20180801_135622.mp4*

[**Here is my html file**](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SKGmIs4qO3MzapZx6M7aFG8sXX5jA6jT)

[**Here is the code related to it.**](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RndPcsdYBw7UbUfeJDtiUTgZ-jUPFAL4)

Please help me with this....

Comment: did you find solution?